# How should I send notifications with push notifications thru FCM for both Android and iOS?

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to both Android and iOS devices using FCM. The front end was coded with Flutter. I am working with Typescript/NestJS at the back end. For some reason, iOS devices receive all the notifications with a push notification/pop-up but Android devices sometimes don't. Strangely, the notifications ALL arrive at the test device INBOXES. It's just that sometimes, Android devices do not show a pop-up/push notification.

Targeting users thru a Firebase topic works as expected: push notifications do arrive for Android and iOS. I do have to find and filter out the users to target before sending the target device IDs to FCM. I am confident my filters are correct. The notifications arrive in the app inbox for both Android and iOS after my filtering. Also, changing the device ID/token in my database causes an error from FCM:

`{"code":"messaging/registration-token-not-registered","message":"Requested entity was not found."}`

If I revert the data to its original values, the app runs fine. I've checked and compared the data I pass to Node.js' FCM module and it looks fine. Here, `messaging` is an instance of `firebaseAdmin.messaging()`.

```
param = {
    "android": {
        "data": {
            "id": "67bcd478-f643-4c9e-848a-be354a6b85d4",
            "icon": "default",
            "title": "Test",
            "body": "Direct From Playground"
        }
    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "id": "67bcd478-f643-4c9e-848a-be354a6b85d4",
                "icon": "default",
                "title": "Announcements",
                "body": "Direct From Playground",
                "alert": {
                    "title": "Announcements",
                    "body": "Direct From Playground"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

messaging.sendMulticast({
    tokens: value as string[],
    ...param,
});
```

Again, the code above sometimes successfully triggers push/pop-up notifications on Android devices but ALWAYS on iOS. Could this be a problem for the front-end handling of my data? Am I missing some parameters?

Comment: I guess you are not handling notifications at client end properly. Use this link for handling messages https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#message_handling. Use Flutter local notifications package to show notifications https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: @Programmer007: Would adding a `notification` object for Android devices make a difference? I do not get any `invalid-argument` or `invalid-payload` errors, but it might be something to check. It would be tedious since I cannot trigger the notifications from my PC. I would have to deploy it to the server.

Comment: No Notification object does not matter. you can add only data object then handle it thorough above methods onMessage() for foreground and onBackgroundMessage() for background messages.

Comment: It was an issue with the device itself. For some reason, using your work profile on Android to test prevented the notifications from arriving. I'll check the other failed cases and see if that is the solution.